# Copy d3 chart to clipboard

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Short Question:

I have a chart generated via d3.js.

I want to copy it to other applications as, for Example to powerpoint.

Is there a possibility to save a chart, generated via d3.js, to clipboard (optimally as jpeg)?

Thank you!

Comment: This is too broad, because D3 can manipulate HTML elements, svg, canvas etc. Is this an SVG? If yes, set all the styles in the code (not in the CSS!) and copy/paste the SVG to an editor like illustrator or Inkscape. From there you can export as a JPEG. This is the most straightforward way. If you search "export svg as JPEG" here at SO you're gonna find several different alternatives.